# Using forward slashes in umbracoUrlName

Tags: path, directory, umbraco, slash

I'm trying to transfer an existing .NET site into Umbraco and trying to use the umbracoUrlName to set the URLs for pages to map to their existing URLs so that inbound links still work and it doesn't affect SEO.  I'd really rather avoid forwarding, but the problem is that some of these pages are in different folders and umbracoUrlName seems to ignore slashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, `umbracoUrlName` ignores slashes. You will either have to put redirects in place using something like the [301 Url Tracker](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/301-url-tracker) or place the nodes inside other nodes to simulate the folder structure.

Alternatively, you could use `umbracoUrlAlias` which does accept forward slashes. This doesn't change the original url, but it does give the page an alias that can also be used to access the node.

Comment: That's pretty annoying.  If I change the node structure then it will muck up the menu, so that isn't really an option.  I'm pretty new to Umbraco development.  Is there a way to override the umbracoUrlName more directly, eg. developing a package, editing the DB table directly etc?

Comment: I don't know anything about that, but you may try using umbracoUrlAlias instead. I edited my answer with more details.

Comment: Were you ever able to figure out something on this that worked for you?

Comment: Not really - ended up having to settle for using 301 Url Tracker, which wasn't quite the functionality I wanted

Comment: Did you take a look at all at umbracoUrlAlias?

Comment: Yeah, I did, but if I couldn't keep the old URL as primary, I didn't want to have 2 flying around - felt messy, so I thought forwarding is better.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old issue and it depends what version of Umbraco you're on but look at the IUrlProvider to solve your issue - this blog post has all the details:
http://24days.in/umbraco/2014/urlprovider-and-contentfinder/